# How to get count of distinct subitems per item?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given a table that looks like this:

```
DATE    USER         TYPE        DEPT
3/1/13  Team1        Add         Finance
3/1/13  Team1        Add         Collections
3/2/13  Team1        Delete      Finance
3/2/13  Team1        Delete      Finance
3/2/13  Team1        Delete      Finance
3/3/13  Team1        Delete      Collections
3/3/13  Team1        Change      Finance
3/3/13  Team1        Change      Finance
3/4/13  Team1        Add         Finance
3/5/13  Team1        Delete      Collections
```

How can I get output like this?

```
TYPE        DEPT        COUNT
Add         Collections 1
Add         Finance     2
Change      Collections 0 (note: this line could be omitted if COUNT = 0)
Change      Finance     2
Delete      Collections 2
Delete      Finance     3
```

I need to specify that USER = Team1 and a date range as well. I have the following so far, but it's not working:

```
SELECT user, type, Count(*) AS Total
FROM table1
GROUP BY user, type
HAVING (((user)="Team1"));
```

This gives me:

```
USER    TYPE    Total
Team1   Add     3
Team1   Change  2
Team1   Delete  5
```

But doesn't break it down by DEPT and I'm not sure how to specify the date range.

As always, thank you!!

EDIT: I think I figured it out:

```
SELECT User, Type, Dept, Count(*) AS Total
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Date) Between #3/1/2013# And #3/5/2013#))
GROUP BY User, Type, Dept
HAVING (((User)="Team1"));
```

Comment: If it weren't Access, I'd say `SELECT type,dept,COUNT(*) count
FROM Table1
WHERE user='Team1'
  AND date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31' 
GROUP BY type,dept;`, but access always has a few surprises in store :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I found similar stuff during a Google search, but Access doesn't like using COUNT that way. Gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this.

```
SELECT Type, Dept, Count(*) AS Total
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Date) Between #3/1/2013# And #3/5/2013#))
AND (((User)="Team1"))
GROUP BY Type, Dept
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to group on TYPE and DEPT and put USER in a where clause:

```
select TYPE, DEPT, count(*) as TOTAL
from table1 where USER = 'Team1'
group by TYPE, DEPT
having TOTAL > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend `GROUP BY` with `DEPT` column:

```
GROUP BY user, type, dept
```

To satisfy date range condition add `WHERE` part:

```
WHERE date >= startDate AND date <= endDate
```

To get data for one user only add another `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE user = "Team1"
```

Whole query should look like that:

```
SELECT user, type, dept, Count(*) AS Total
FROM table1
WHERE date >= startDate AND date <= endDate AND user = "Team1"
GROUP BY user, type, dept
```

You dont have to do anything to remove rows with `Total = 0` - they wan't be there because items with that `type` and `dept` are not in group source.

Comment: actually, this didn't group by Dept :(